# Laravel Datatables adding column with specific html

Tags: laravel, datatables

I have a problem with adding column into the jquery.datatables.

My datatable function looks like this

```
 public function getSliderImages()
{

    $query = Slider::with('User')->select('sliders.*');

    return Datatables::of($query)
        ->addColumn('fullName',function ($data){
            return $data->user->firstName .' '. $data->user->lastName;
        })
        ->addColumn('types',function ($data){
            return '<ul class="list-condensed list-unstyled no-margin">' .
                '<li><span class="text-semibold">Boyut:</span> '.$data->size.'</li>' .
                '<li><span class="text-semibold">Format:</span> ' .$data->ext.'</li></ul>';
        })

        ->make(true);
}
```

The returning json file is pretty good however here is the problem
My datatable looks like this[image: it acts as a raw text not as a html]

And last thing is my javascript

```
columns: [
                {data: 'slider_slug', name: 'slider_slug',"render": function(data, type, row) {
                    return '<a href="'+loc+'/'+data+'" data-popup="lightbox"> <img src="'+loc+'/'+data+'" class="img-rounded img-preview" </a>';
                },

                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
                {data: 'slider_slug', name: 'slider_slug'},
                {data: 'fullName', name: 'fullName'},
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                {data: 'action',name:'action'},
                {data: 'types',name:'types'},
```

The returning value is acts like a plain text but its html.

In the javascript I couldnt get 2 data from server.I mean I cannot get 2 variables in 1 row.

How can I solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have the solution to your problem, try this

```
 columns: [
              {data: 'slider_slug', name: 'slider_slug',
                            render:function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                console.log(full);
                                return '<a href="'+loc+'/'+data+'" data-popup="lightbox"> <img src="'+loc+'/'+data+'" class="img-rounded img-preview" </a>';
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: I cannot use this because I need two data here. Both $data->ext and $data->size

Comment: Why downvote? With full you can retrieve the values ​​of all the other columns

Comment: can you explain more ? btw I didnt downvoted I was searching

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Oh, np :) bye !

Answer (score 5):

Simple...
just add `->rawColumns(['fullName', 'types'])`

So... your code will be:

```
public function getSliderImages()
{

    $query = Slider::with('User')->select('sliders.*');

    return Datatables::of($query)
        ->addColumn('fullName',function ($data){
            return $data->user->firstName .' '. $data->user->lastName;
        })
        ->addColumn('types',function ($data){
            return '<ul class="list-condensed list-unstyled no-margin">' .
                '<li><span class="text-semibold">Boyut:</span> '.$data->size.'</li>' .
                '<li><span class="text-semibold">Format:</span> ' .$data->ext.'</li></ul>';
        })
        ->rawColumns(['fullName', 'types'])
        ->make(true);
}
```

See https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/raw-columns

Answer (score 1):

please use new rawColumns() method. you have to pass an array or columns that you need to be displayed as raw columns ( with HTML rendered)

example:
(driver and action column will be rendered as raw - with HTML)

```js
rawColumns(['driver','action'])
```